# What should be the first commit message using commitlint?

Tags: commit, git-commit, commitlint

If I am using @commitlint/config-conventional, what should be my first commit message using commmitlint? Is it feat: first commit or a build: first commit or a chore: first commit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good first commit would be to describe your new project with a README:

```
docs: add README
```

That way, you can start implementing in subsequent commits what you just described.